# which web framework should i choose

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, web-applications

i company has some old project which is used asp.net(WebForms)

now we have a new project,i suggested to use java or php to implement ,but we team just can do c#.net

the project need stable,efficient in High concurrency and a large data

I want to choose .NET MVC3 or .NET MVC4 with others, beacause i am feeling the performance is not good for asp.net(WebForms).

so someone can give me some suggestion?

```
1.asp.net(WebForms)
2.asp.net MVC3
3.asp.net MVC4
```

please write down your reasons if you can.

In addition, my English is poor, can express simple some.

thanks!

Comment: You don't think asp.net is good, so you want to use asp.net?

Comment: just WebForms,a lot of _viewState and it is hard to Cooperate with js

Comment: The performance of asp.net webforms is super fast, and together with the easy to programming make it a really strong tool. But the speed is depended from the programmer and not by the language. Even if you have a formula one, if you do not know to run it's stops http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EGUZJVY-sHo

Comment: Its always better to go for MVC 4 ,because it has a feature called "Web api controller" which acts like a REST service without any configuration settings. And basically MVC is chosen for testablility which is ahead of forms submission.But remember MVC is not a replacement for forms in asp .net.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no reason to choose old MVC3 over MVC4.
Actually take a look at MVC5 (http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction/getting-started), which will be released with Visual Studio 2013.

Starting from VS2013 there will be only one ASP.NET project so it really doesn't matter if you want to develop WebForms, MVC or sinle page application with Web API backend.

PS. StackOverflow runs on .NET so I think you have your proof that you can run high-performance web app on .NET stack.

Comment: thank you!I always feel  there are a lot of unstable and bug in the new framework. I tend to choose high maturity usually stable good part, so we said MVC 3 or MVC4

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your project is an enterprise level application, so you should have an infrastructure that covers all of your project's requirements.

I recommend you using "Domain Driven Design" approach which is implemented and well documented in (Microsoft Spain - Domain Oriented N-Layered .NET 4.0 Sample App) http://microsoftnlayerapp.codeplex.com.

By using "Domain Driven Design", it's not very important what is your front-end technology, you can use ASP.NET, ASP.NET MVC, Silverlight, WPF, etc.

Don't worry about performance, there are other factors that determine what kind of front-end technology must be choosen, http://www.devcurry.com/2009/09/difference-between-aspnet-webforms-and.html might be helpful.

Comment: the project is a Information acquisition and analysis system.

Comment: There are wide variety of open source tools over ASP.NET (MVC) can help to implement cutting-edge aspects of web applications in  Information acquisition and analysis system that you mentioned, those tools improve the quality and user experience significantly.

Comment: thanks for @Abbas Amiri.I am really not familiar with specific to.net,so ......